# how make a laravel pagination component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

I have a slider component with a back and forward button and I want to get data in sort of pagination how can I do this?
I just want to do this without using Vue.js or livewire just laravel , JS and JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's Query Builder provides a `paginate` method that gives you a `LengthAwarePaginator`. Normally, you would render this in a blade view with `$items->links()`, but instead you can convert its result to JSON (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json). That way you can use the results in JavaScript any way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

First, why using slider to create a pagination? there are better approach like lazy load, filter column, and simple pagination. lazy load is best for performance i guess.

If you insist to create a slider component, just wondering, how many data that you have? and how many data that you want to retrieve to screen? Imagine, you have more than 1.000.000 rows in your database, you sure wouldn't want to query for them all for real time updates to your screen. Why i tell you 'query them all'?

Let me tell you, if you do a pagination using laravel default pagination (using limit and offset), the flow behind this is like this:

1. DB will select all of your rows that you have
2. DB will limit your row depends on limit parameter
3. DB will scan row one-by-one to match the offset that you want
4. DB will retrieve the data that you want

With that flow, that's why pagination (limit & offset) is not good enough if you have a lot of data. The solution is change your pagination logic from limit & offset to query like this (case: auto incremental id):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    payments
WHERE
  Id > 15
LIMIT 20
```

or for descending approach, you can query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    payments
WHERE
  Id < 50
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Then in laravel, send a json that include a pagination data. So, in javascript you just have to align the pagination data with library or your own pagination logic.